# Passwords/username from a file

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I've recently been having trouble writing a program that involves taking the password and username from a .txt file. So far I have written:

```
username_file = open("usernameTest1.txt","rt")
name = username_file.readlines()
username_file.close()
print(username_file)
print(name)
print(name[0])
print()

print(name[1])
Player1Name = name[0]
print(Player1Name)
nametry = ""
while nametry != (name[0]):
    while True:
        try:
            nametry = input("What is your Username player1?: ")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Not a valid input")
```

(The various prints are to help me to see what the error is)
The password is successfully extracted from the file however when it is put into a variable and put through an `if` statement, it doesn't work!

Any help would be much appreciated!
Hopefully this is a simple fix!

Comment: Can you post the first 3, 4 lines of your input text file?

Comment: There is no `if` statement in your code. Also, please clarify what "doesn't work" mean.

Comment: This needs to be tagged with either Python 2.x or Python 3.x, as `input()` works rather differently between the two.

Comment: Swadhikar C - The text file does not matter all it does is store the password and username.

Comment: pushkin - it keeps repeating the while statement despite putting in the right password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that readlines() function lets the \n character remain in your text lines and that causes the texts to not match. You can use this instead when opening the file:

```
name = username_file.read().splitlines()
```

give it a try.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked perfectly and it split the two Usernames up! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the readlines function doen't strip the newline character from the end of the lines, so eventough you wrote "samplename" as input, it won't equal "samplename\n".
You can try this:

```
name = [x.rstrip() for x in username_file.readlines()]
```